# Implementing ssl on glassfish 4.0 on localhost

Tags: web-services, security, ssl, glassfish, restful-authentication

I am using a glassfish server and implementing Rest webservices which can be consumed from web or mobile clients. 
I now want to secure these webservices using ssl certificates and create a session between client and server. I have not yet purchased any domain name or server space and trying to build it on my local machine.
How do i configure a free ssl certificate for glassfish on my localhost.

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: is it not already pre configured for you?

Comment: Not sure, how do i check that?

Comment: i have to make my rest services accessible only through https://

Answer (score 3):

Hotcoder24,

As far as I understand the problem from your question and comment, you want to communicate with your service via HTTPS. This is a snap when you use an application server. In fact, this is done with configuration in your web.xml file.

Let's start with a simple web application created using maven archetype jersey-quickstart-webapp, described in [Jersey tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-webapp).

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example -DarchetypeVersion=2.14
```

This creates a web application containing a single resource, which can be deployed to a Glassfish server (a war-file is produced).

```
@Path("myresource")
```

public class MyResource {

```
/**
 * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
 * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
 *
 * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    return "Got it!";
}
```

}

First of all, you should create a user and add it to a group using Glassfish console (`http://localhost:4848/`). The simplest way to start is to use a file realm. The process is described [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/security-webapps.html#Creating_users_roles). Let's create a user called “user” and group called “users”.

If you deploy the application, the resource will be available in your browser if you enter a URL `http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/webapi/myresource`. Before we have done any configuration in the project's xml files, the resource is freely available.

Now let's add some elements to your web.xml file.

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!--Some elements go here-->

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>GetIt</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>users</role-name>
</security-role>
```

We added tree elements:

- security-constraint which describes a URL pattern to protect, lists roles allowed to access it and most important to your question is the user-data-constraint element, which in our case switches on the HTTPS.
- login-config element instructs the server to use the simplest authenticated mechanism which means, that when you try to access the resource using a browser, a dialog prompting for login and password is displayed to you; also you realm's name is enshrined here;
- the last element defines roles you use.

Now it is necessary that groups are linked to roles. This is done using a container-specific glassfish-web.xml.

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>users</role-name>
    <group-name>users</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<!--some elements go here-->
```

Now if you direct your browser to a http:// URL, you'll be switched to https://, which is not the case without the   user-data-constraint element with `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description dude..
I appreciate your effort.. wish i could upvote ur answer several times..